# Can't check if more than 1 post data isset in the same if statement

Tags: php, validation

I'm trying to validate data but I'm having trouble.

The problem is I am checking if certain post data is set. Problem is it's either always set or not, i think it's because I am trying to check for multiple things in an incorrect format in my if statement?

I think it's only this line that is incorrect but I am having some sort of mental block.

I understand it is probably something quite trivial but I can't think of a way to word it to find a solution via Google.

```
if ((!isset($_POST['first_name'])) || (!isset($_POST['contact_no'])) || (!isset($_POST['device'])) || (!isset($_POST['fault']))) {
echo 'no Name, contact number, device or fault given.';
}
```

I know i could check in separate if's but I would really like to refresh how i check multiple items in the same statement..

After trying suggestions, without any luck, adding more information:

```
if (isset($_POST['posted']) == 'TRUE') {
$error = array();
    if( !isset($_POST['first_name']) ){ $error[] = 'no Name given.'; }
elseif( !isset($_POST['contact_no']) ){ $error[] = 'no contact number given.'; }
elseif( !isset($_POST['device']) ) {    $error[] = 'no Device given.'; }
elseif( !isset($_POST['fault']) ) {     $error[] = 'no fault given.'; }

if( count($error)!==0){
    echo 'Error(s) occured:<br />'.implode('<br />', $errors);
}
else {
$db->query("INSERT INTO repairs (r_oem, r_device, r_mod, r_reserve, r_price, r_s_date, r_e_date, r_notes, rc_fname, rc_lname, rc_email, rc_contactno, rc_return, rc_status, rc_status_2, rc_status_txt, rc_status_txt_2, booked_by, passcode) VALUES( '$make', '$device', '$model', '$fault', '$price', '$date', '$date2', '$notes', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$cno', '','$status', '', '', '', '$bookedby', '$pass')");
$get_id = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$print_id = $db->fetch_row($get_id);
$last_r_id_insterted = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `repairs` ORDER BY `repairs`.`r_id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$plrid = $db->fetch_row($last_r_id_insterted);
echo '<br />';
echo <<<EOF
<script>
alert("Successfully created record for {$fname} {$lname}\'s {$make} {$device} {$model}. Job Reference: {$plrid['r_id']}");
 </script>
 EOF;
 print "<span style='float: left; margin-left:25px;'><a class='button positive' 'href=\"print_label.php?ref={$plrid['r_id']}\" target=\"_blank\">Printable Sticky Label.</a></span><span class='fright'><a class='button positive' href=\"print_card.php?ref={$plrid['r_id']}\" target=\"_blank\">Printable Customer Card.</a></span><br /><br />";
if (isset($_POST['item1'])) {
        $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part1id={$_POST['item1']} WHERE r_id={$plrid['r_id']}");
        $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited+1, s_count=s_count-1 WHERE id={$_POST['item1']}");   
}
if (isset($_POST['item2'])) {
        $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part2id={$_POST['item2']} WHERE r_id={$plrid['r_id']}");
        $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited+1, s_count=s_count-1 WHERE id={$_POST['item2']}");
}
if (isset($_POST['item3'])) {

        $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part3id={$_POST['item3']} WHERE r_id={$plrid['r_id']}");
        $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited+1, s_count=s_count-1 WHERE id={$_POST['item3']}");
}
if (isset($_POST['item4'])) {
        $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part4id={$_POST['item4']} WHERE r_id={$plrid['r_id']}");
        $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited+1, s_count=s_count-1 WHERE id={$_POST['item4']}");           
}
if (isset($_POST['item5'])) {

        $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part5id={$_POST['item5']} WHERE r_id={$plrid['r_id']}");
        $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited+1, s_count=s_count-1 WHERE id={$_POST['item5']}");
}
else {
    print "No Parts Selected<br />";
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: "Problem is its either always set or not" - I don't understand this statement.

Comment: What I mean is no matter how I change the format of the statement, the that if statement ALWAYS runs regardless of data in the POST.

Comment: The error in your code is the 2nd `)` after firstname. You close the if-staement with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of, you can compact it a lot by joining the values in isset:

```
if ( isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['contact_no'], $_POST['device'], $_POST['fault']) ) {}
```

Please note that I dont use the `!` to reverse. `isset()` returns false if one of the values is not set.
I think you are looking for `if( isset($_POST) ){ /* ... */ }`.

---

Apart from that, I'm not really sure what you mean, but I think something like this:

```
if( isset($_POST) ){
        if( !isset($_POST['first_name']) ){ echo 'no Name given.'; }
    elseif( !isset($_POST['contact_no']) ){ echo 'no contact number given.'; }
    elseif( !isset($_POST['device']) ) {    echo 'no Device given.'; }
    elseif( !isset($_POST['fault']) ) {     echo 'no fault given.'; }
    else{
       echo "everything OK";
    }
}
```

---

Another method would be concating strings:

```
if( isset($_POST) ){
    $error = array();
        if( !isset($_POST['first_name']) ){ $error[] = 'no Name given.'; }
    elseif( !isset($_POST['contact_no']) ){ $error[] = 'no contact number given.'; }
    elseif( !isset($_POST['device']) ) {    $error[] = 'no Device given.'; }
    elseif( !isset($_POST['fault']) ) {     $error[] = 'no fault given.'; }

    if( count($error)!==0){
        echo 'Error(s) occured:<br />'.implode('<br />', $errors);
    }
    else{
       echo "everything OK";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that is what I want, i can write it like that, but what i wanted was to have them all in the same IF statement.

Comment: I think I have all options in my post. I think it's the `isset($_POST)` what you are looking for :)

Comment: your first line is what i was looking for, i had it very similar to begin with but had '||' in place of your ',' and was getting T_BOOLEAN error. Thank you!

Comment: Actually i can't get any of your suggestions to work, i will add more information in initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You can check $_POST vars with

```
    if(isset($_POST))
    {

    }
```

and then validate every single key of $_POST var

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']))
     echo "no name";
    elseif(!isset($_POST['contact_no']))
     echo "no number";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use something like

```
$_POST['first_name'] == ""
```

I believe that as long as the field first_name is included in the form, it isset() even if it does not contain any data.

Sample code (submit the form with and without the input field filled in, same results:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
        echo "it's set!";
}
?>
<form method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='first_name'/>
        <input type='submit' value='submit'/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a function:

```
function fieldIsSet($field) {
  if(is_array($field) {
    foreach($field as $f) {
      if( ! fieldIsSet($f)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    if( !isset($_POST[$field]) || empty($_POST[$field])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
// with an string[]
fieldIsSet(array('first_name', 'contact_no', 'device', 'fault')) or echo 'no Name, contact number, device or fault given.';

// with a single string
fieldIsSet('first_name') or echo 'no Name given.';
```

Comment: how do i put this in an if statement, so that is there is data in those, i can run my else with the query etc

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved by using

if($_POST.length<4){…your code…},

assuming that you send only 4 variables through the post request.